# Powershell URL image to FTP

Tags: url, powershell, ftp, send

i'm trying to use powershell to take image from specified url and resend it to ftp.
But it doesn't work this way :/

```
$url = "http://somesite.com/image.jpg"
$ftp = "ftp://username:password@hostname.com/folder/image.jpg"

$webclient = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
$uri = New-Object System.Uri($ftp)

$webclient.UploadFile($uri, $url)
```

Any tips?
Thanx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The WebClient and FtpWebRequest class in .NET (and consequently PowerShell) don't support the [**F**ile e**X**change **P**rotocol (FXP)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_eXchange_Protocol) - as such you will need to download the source file to your computer first, then transfer the file over FTP to your destination:

```
$source = "http://somesite.com/image.jpg"
$destination = "ftp://username:password@hostname.com/folder/image.jpg"

$webclient = New-Object System.Net.WebClient

$webclient.DownloadFile($source, "temp.jpg")
$webclient.UploadFile($destination, "temp.jpg")
```